# Как сделать валюту товара от курса $ на javascript

Tags: php, javascript

как вывести на страницу после обращения к функции getrates подробности [тут](http://yournet.kz/blog/php/parsing-kursa-valyut-nacionalnogo-banka-kazakhstana)

Comment: Стоп, ложная тревога. Не спам, просто ссылка на код.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, поздно пить боржоми ;)

Comment: @Visman: да ладно, вот даже ответ успели дать.

Answer (score 1):

Вы не поверите, но ответ банален, надо взять курс доллара из данных и умножить на цену товара.

К сожалению, поскольку никаких дополнительных данных вы не привели, придется ограничиться этим. Все остальное зависит от того, насколько хорошо вы знаете PHP что бы сделать функцию getrates под себя и каким образом будет организованна доставка данных из этого самого PHP в JavaScript. Ну и конечно, как у вас там организована DOM страница в плане расположения ценников.